# how to get current system network IPv4 Address Using Apex in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

In my computer start<> Controlpanel<> NetworkAccoess<> details <>IPv4 Address

Connection-specific DNS Suffix: 
Description: Qualcomm Atheros AG8161/8165 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)
Physical Address: ‎00-8C-FB-6B-F5-C1
DHCP Enabled: No
IPv4 Address: 192.168.25.68
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.169.99.1
IPv4 DNS Server: 192.169.10.7
IPv4 WINS Server:

How to get my system network IPv4 Address Using APEX in Salesforce?

help me

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of googling is not that difficult:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giq9AAA
http://abhithetechknight.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/ip-address-on-visualforce-page.html
http://learn4sfdc.blogspot.com.au/2014/01/how-to-get-ip-address-of-user-in-apex.html

Basically the IP address can be obtained from the headers of the reqest made to the VF page.

Comment: I want below path ipAddress not Internet current ip address                     start<> Controlpanel<> NetworkAccoess<> details <>IPv4 Address                        using Apex in salesforce how to get IPv4 Address?

Comment: There is no way to do that, it would be very dangerous if that was possible :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the private (RFC1918 space) IP of the client. That's not sent as part of the network request, as for the why you'll need to read up on [network address translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

You can get the public IP of the client by checking HTTP headers as Bachovski pointed out.